# Is jquery 1.x's live, live as in life or live as in a live tv show?

Tags: jquery

I know it is deprecated, but I always thought it was live, like a live tv show, because it bound events "live" as they were created.

But when reading through the removed functions documentation I discovered there was a die method that removed events, so now I'm wondering if it was live as in life - the opposite of die? live and die?

Most devs I know say live (like a TV show) - what is correct?

Comment: Life is a paradox, a mirror on a wall of confusion.

Comment: For some reason, I see this question asked the third time this week. The others were closed if memory serves. The question is primarily opinion-based unless someone from the jQuery development team actually created a pronunciation guide, which I highly doubt.

Comment: Then what was the answer? I really want to know - funny I googled this and never found an answer

Comment: Yeah but, for all intents and puposes, it added a bind to a dom element as it was dynamically added to the dom. I know technically that it was a bind on the document

Comment: @RISCOS It did not really add a bind. It just caught events that bubbled up to `document` and ran the handler if the element that the event fired on matched the selector.

Comment: @RISCOS Those questions were all deleted, but this seems to be the closest you can get to an answer: https://twitter.com/brandonaaron/status/5639993923 (Brandon Aaron is a former jQuery core developer)

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's neither alive nor realtime. It's rather frozen and reanimated when needed.

The `live` method would bind an event handler on the document, that would catch any event of that type that bubbles through the DOM hierarchy all the way to the top. When that happens, it would re-evaluate its selector to find any elements that match it at that time.

Although convenient when needed, it could make the page quite sluggish if overused. The `delegate` method was introduced to allow the same way of handling events, but for a smaller scope than the entire document.